# Android: Swipe on custom list view layout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-adapter, android-gesture

I am developing an application in which i am having a list view with custome adapter.

The adapter consist of some view as shown in image :

[image]

In the image - image view are there followed by text view followed by relative layout in red having text view.

All the text view are clickable.

What my requirement is :

I want to apply swipe on relative layout in red as same as android is having swipe and call functionality.As below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this lib
https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss

You have to provide your custom style to the animation